# Tor with Windows RT

Tags: windows

I get as present a used Surface 1 with Windows RT 8.1.

Is there a possiblity to use Tor on a Windows RT Tablet?

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Yes, it's possible - you can compile it from source *with* MinGW as well.